# Confusion with the change of boundaries

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

[image]

[image]

I am not quite sure why they use those boundaries for finding the marginal distribution function for $y$. Isn't it supposed to be $[0,1]$? Since $x$ is in $[0,1]$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The condition $x^2 < y$ yields $x < \sqrt{y}$ by taking square roots. The condition $y < \sqrt{x}$ yields $x > y^2$ by taking squares. Hence $x$ varies in $(y^2, \sqrt{y})$.